# Get specific recordset value using MAX

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, bids

I have the following condition:

```
=MAX(Fields!CodeCount.Value, "Query1") & " " & First(Fields!CodeVal.Value, "Query1")
```

Which yields 3 ABC

Now I need to find the MAX and three is the correct answer but I don't need it beyond evaluating so what I want to stuff into a report variable is "ABC".

So how do I eval for the MAX but only assign the CodeVal.Value into my report variable?

TIA
JB

Comment: It appears to me that the code you posted is unconditional.  You're going to get "ABC" no matter what you do.  The MAX and FIRST clauses are independent of each other.  Perhaps if we had a clearer idea of what you are trying to accomplish, you'd get a prompter response.

Comment: Not being clear...Guilty as charged. As for being unconditional I'm not so sure. Let me edit with more details and hopefully that will help with understanding.